# How to update Bootstrap-4 to Angular-js

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

Im create Bootstrap-4 project(website) ,But now I want to update this project for the  Angular-js , I want to know how to use bootstrap tag to angular,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what exactly your problem is. But if you want a proper integration of angular and bootstrap you can use angular bootstrap directive, have a look at this directive [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Sir then , can I use both component  , example `bootstrap drop down`, some pages are `angular table `

Comment: Yes you can do that , These are angular directives so it is possible

Comment: Sir i got some information https://www.bootstrapdash.com/use-bootstrap-4-with-angular/